# Reusing Less variables and classes inside functions

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to reuse classes inside of a Less function that is a variable?

Example:

```
@red: #F16251;

.smalltext { font-size: 10px }
.mediumtext { font-size: 12px }
.largetext { font-size: 14px }
.xtralargetext { font-size: 20px }

.myfunction(@size: smalltext, @color: @red) {
    @.{size}; /*  This will need to call the class defined above */
    color: @color;
}
```

How can this be done, if possible?  The `@.{size}` throws an error.  I would just like to call the function like so:

```
.myfunction(mediumtext, #000000);
```

and would like it to use the `.mediumtext` class rule.  Possible?  I am getting a compilation error on above code btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no, currently we can't assign a mixin to a variable nor call a mixin by its name. For your example however there's "DR-based" (see [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature)) way:

```
.medium-text {font-size: 12px}

.my-mixin(@size, @color) {
    @size();
    color: @color;
}

.foo {
    .my-mixin({.medium-text}, red);
}
```

Comment: I was just drafting something very similar:) Happy New Year!

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thanks that helps with calling the class rule I need to call.  I had started to do a bunch of `when` statements, that also works, but is very tiresome and a lot of conditions.  My example was a small example of a huge headache across multiple less files.  Atleast this is possible without using `when`.  Cheers and Happy New Years!

Comment: There're other tricks (that may be more convenient for some other use-cases) - see for example https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1648#issuecomment-33861048 (and other posts referenced there).